# Conditionally Prepend text to title tag base on character count using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to prepend text to my page title tags using jquery based on the number of characters in the title.

I want to prepend text to the title say if the character count is <= 30

I have had some success with :

```
         $(document).ready(function(){
         if ( $('title').length > 0 ){
              $('title').prepend('mytext');
             }
             })
```

But this only works on the total character count so if i enter > 200 then it will not append the text if i enter > 0 it will append the text but <=30 does not work so I think I'm looking for the code that will count each page title on load then apply the condition.

I hope this make sense ..!!

Thanks

Comment: First your question makes no sense. Secondly `$('title').length` counts the number of `title` tags in the page, not the length of the text in the `title` tag.

Comment: Not much sense, unfortunately. You might want to rephrase that.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan  yes thanks for that... but it was why i was asking the question ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should go with something like this:

```
if ( $("title").text().length <= 30 ){
    $('title').prepend('mytext');
}
```

Comment: You missed the part where he only wants to prepend if the length is `<= 30`

Comment: I did not miss it but just modified the code so that he can put any condition he want. Anyways, thanks for commenting. Will keep it in mind for next time :)

Comment: @Ganesh Pandhere thanks for the answer i've got some good feed back here will see which one works the best for me..thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JQuery for this one.

Use `document.title` instead of your selector (which selects all title tags).

`document.title` is a simple read/write property for the page title.

### e.g.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var title = document.title;
     if ( title.length <=30 ){
         document.title = 'mytext' + title;
     }
 })
```

Minimalist version:

```
 if ( document.title.length <=30 ){
     document.title = 'mytext' + document.title;
 }
```

Of you you do prefer JQuery the answer by Ganesh Pandhere also works.

Comment: thanks for the answer I'm going to test the suggestions and see which one works best for me  ...

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing there is only one title. You are counting the number of titles. You should rather do this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var title = $('title').eq(0);
     if ( title.text().length > 0 ){
          title.prepend('mytext');
     }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple tags on one page, it would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('h2').each(function(){
        if($(this).html().length < 30){
            $(this).prepend('Hi, this is ');
        }
    });
});
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/danieltulp/u2tPH/